# URL rewriting not working in Server but does in Localhost

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I have a code in my config.php file,

```
// If URL-Rewriting does not work then set
// define('BASE_PATH',BASE_DIR.'/index.php');
// If URL-Rewriting works, then leave the line below as is
define('BASE_PATH',BASE_DIR);
```

This Works Good in my localhost machine, but does not work in the Server I host, So I made a .`htaccess` file and wrote `RewriteEngine On` in it. Still not working. What may be the Problem

Comment: Are you sure that the server has mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: What else is in the .htaccess? `RewriteEngine on` only enables it, you need to specify some rules too.

Comment: modrewrite.tags is enabled.. the .htaccess file only contains one line.. Thats rewriteengine on.. thats it

Comment: Since I am using an open source code from http://anantgarg.com/2009/12/09/php-stackoverflow-clone/ ... It works Cool even without modrewrite in my local host with seo friendly urls

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have some ssh access to your server?
Try this command: `a2enmod rewrite`

And add some rules to your .htaccess file. [see this](http://www.lavluda.com/2007/07/15/how-to-enable-mod_rewrite-in-apache22-debian/)

Comment: thanks @helle.. But i just found that.. from my hosting provider that I need to upgrade my account to get access to it

Comment: is it enabled? you can check it by reading the info, printed out, when giving `phpinfo();`

Comment: Yes modrewrite.tags is enabled